# Python make_scorer giving incorrect outputs for Root Mean Square Logarithmic Error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to generate a grid search for which I need the `scoring` parameter based on which the search will take place. I have defined the following function to provide me a `Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error`. But I feel that the scorer is considering the greater value to be a better score, whereas it should consider the lower value as better score. Please let me know if I have defined a correct scorer.

**Function for RMSLE**

```
def score_func(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
  y_true = np.abs(y_true)
  y_pred = np.abs(y_pred)

  return np.sqrt(mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred))

scorer = make_scorer(score_func)
```

I had to use `np.abs` in the above code, otherwise it was giving an error that RMSLE cannot be used when Target has negative values.

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82433/55122

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import math

#Function to calculate Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (RMSLE)
def rmsle(y, y_pred):
    assert len(y) == len(y_pred)
    terms_to_sum = [(math.log(y_pred[i] + 1) - math.log(y[i] + 1)) ** 2.0 for i,pred in enumerate(y_pred)]
    return (sum(terms_to_sum) * (1.0/len(y))) ** 0.5
```

Comment: Can you please comment on my function that I have created to calculate the same. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes @IshanDutta

Comment: For better visibility of under the hood calculations, I would suggest using the solution which I have mentioned.